# Make object circular around one axis

Tags: mesh, modifiers

I'm sorry if the headline isn't totally perfect but since English isn't my first language it's rather difficult to explain what I try to do right now, so please bear with me. xD
In the pic to be seen is a mesh and inside a sphere. I want the mesh be "circular" around z-axis so it completely surrounds the sphere.
I hope I could make my plan clear. :)
Thanks for the attention.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is geometrically unclear.

What do you expect as the final result?

Here are some variations of an answer, that all fit around the sphere.

Can you identify from one of the following?

[image: variation meshes]

---

Don't really have time to answer this, but see what you can glean from this demo. I'm going to have to circle back around to answer properly as time allows.

[image: demo]

Quick hint I use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> when scaling.

My pivot is set to 3d cursor <kbd>.</kbd>

Snapping is on and set to Verts.

The rest is extrude and fill.

Comment: The one at the front looks to me like it fits the stated requirement from the original poster. Can you please explain how that one is produced?

Comment: Yay, the one in the front/far left is what I need, thank you, would you explain how you did it? :)